# Chrome DevTools Protocol Fetch Domain - getResponseBody - apparently fails with HTTP redirects

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am wishing to collect the body of an HTTP request, including when the page redirects to elsewhere. Clearly, I can use non-Fetch domain mechanisms such as [`Network.getResponseBody`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-getResponseBody). That works fine for the "final" page in a chain of redirections, but cannot be used for the intermediate pages because Chrome appears to dump the content when going to the next redirection target.

So, I implemented [`Fetch.enable`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-enable)`( { patterns: [ { requestStage: Response } ] } )` (using PHP, but the details of that are irrelevant, as you will see). No error is returned from this method call. After then doing a [`Page.navigate`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-navigate), I wait for a [`Fetch.requestPaused`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#event-requestPaused) event which contains members `requestId`, `responseStatusCode` and `responseHeaders` and then send a [`Fetch.getResponseBody`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-getResponseBody) (using the `requestId` from the `Fetch.requestPaused`) and the response I get depends on what the actual response to the page itself was. So, for a `200`, I get a response body (hurray), but for a 30x (`301`, `302` etc), I always get error code `-32000` with the message `"Can only get response body on requests captured after headers received"`. Now, issuing that error message is inconsistent (in my view) with the `Fetch.requestPaused` event data, even if Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP) was not intended to capture the bodies of HTTP redirected pages. By the way, pages with content triggered redirection (via a META element or JavaScript) are captured okay, I assume because they return a 200 status code.

So, is the issue in the sequence of calls I'm following or in the error message returned by `Fetch.getResponseBody` and am I correctly assuming CDP was not intended to capture the bodies of documents in a redirection chain (apart from the last one, obviously)?

Comment: getResponseBody apparently wants the request to be in a paused state but considers a redirected request as a different request (technically it is different AFAIK). If there's no way to pause on redirect automatically then it definitely looks like a bug in CDP or an architectural deficiency.

Comment: Just noticed that in Chrom(ium) that if I open DevTools and use the Network tab, the Response preview pane shows "no response data" (or a similar message) - that supports the idea that it's an architectural deficiency. Interestingly, Firefox did something similar.Looks like I'll have to do a cURL or similar - shame, that's two requests for each intermediate page: the original in CDP and the second in cURL

Answer (score 0):

You need to continue the request on a 301/302 and let the browser follow it (there is no body in a redirect):

```js
    if (
      params.responseStatusCode === 301 || params.responseStatusCode === 302
    ) {
      await this.#client.send('Fetch.continueRequest', {
        requestId,
      });
    } else {
      // get body here
      const responseCdp = await this.#client.send('Fetch.getResponseBody', {
        requestId,
      });
    
      await this.#client.send('Fetch.fulfillRequest', {
        requestId,
        responseCode: params.responseStatusCode,
        responseHeaders: params.responseHeaders,
        body: responseCdp.body,
      });
    }
```

Comment: in my experience, although there *should* be no body in a redirect, there often is (it depends on the site owner / content and also the capabilities of the webserver - Apache, nginx, Tomcat, etc, etc). For my purposes, it is useful to capture that transient content as well as the "final" content. Thanks for the code snippet.